# rows wise correlation between two Dataframe which have unequal columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, correlation

I have two Dataframes, (Dataset1=200rows, 34 column)(Dataset2=200rows, 22 column). I want rows wise correlation between both datasets. how can I perform this. I have applied corrwith function but got NAN for all the rows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: IBD_external.corrwith(IBD_prism, axis=1) I have applied this.